# Solve a LP problem using Pyomo where decision variable can be either positive or negative

Tags: pyomo

I'm trying to solve a LP problem using Pyomo where my decision variable (Pst = Pst+ + Pst-) can be either positive or negative (Pst+ for discharging and Pst- for charging my battery) and it's the same for Pg. I would like to know if it is obligatory to specify the domain as binary so that the solver CPLEX can solve the problem or else how do I specify the domain of my decision variable.

```
    import pyomo.environ as pyo

    model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

    #Défine parameters
    model.Ppv = 5
    model.Pch = 20

    #Power max décharge battery (parameters)
    model.Pbattdechargemax = 10
    model.rendementdecharge = 0.85

    #Power max charge battery (parameters)
    model.Pbattchargemax = -10
    model.rendementcharge = 0.85


    #Défine decision variables
    model.Pg_decharge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals) 
    model.Pg_charge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NegativeReals)
    model.Pst_decharge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    model.Pst_charge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NegativeReals)

    #Objective function
     model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(sense = pyo.minimize, expr = 
     2*model.Pg_decharge + 2*model.Pg_charge + 
     3*model.Pst_decharge + 3*model.Pst_charge)


    #Contraints
    model.Constraint1 = pyo.Constraint(expr = model.Pg_decharge + 
    model.Ppv + model.Pst_decharge == model.Pch)

    model.Constraint2 = pyo.Constraint(expr = model.Pst_decharge 
    <= model.Pbattdechargemax * model.rendementdecharge)
    
    model.Constraint3 = pyo.Constraint(expr = model.Pst_charge >= 
    model.Pbattchargemax / model.rendementcharge)



    ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Pg_decharge
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var.ScalarVar'>)
      No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Pg_decharge
    ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: OBJ
    (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.objective.ScalarObjective'>)
      No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Pg_decharge
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It is typical to post what you have tried so far and what (specifically) is not working.  Have you tried to construct/print your model?  The default domain in pyomo is all real numbers, which sounds appropriate here.  The documentation shows other options.

Comment: #Défine decision variables
model.Pg_decharge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)  
model.Pg_charge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NegativeReals)
model.Pst_decharge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.Pst_charge = pyo.Var(domain=pyo.NegativeReals)



#Objective function
model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(sense = pyo.minimize, expr = 2*model.Pg_decharge + 2*model.Pg_charge + 3*model.Pst_decharge + 3*model.Pst_charge)

Comment: Hello,

In fact I want 2 variables to be only positive and the 2 others to be only negative. Above is a part of my code and the error that I'm obtaining. Thus I would like to know if it is possible to have variables with different domains please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: Pg_decharge
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var.ScalarVar'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Pg_decharge
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: OBJ
        (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.objective.ScalarObjective'>)
    No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Pg_decharge

Comment: Please use the "edit" link above in your original post to add your code and the error...much easier to read!  Move it up and I'll give it a look in a bit.  :)

Comment: It's done. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: the model you posted above does not produce an error code for me.  It is also unbounded.  Why are you splitting up the `pst` variable into positive and negative components instead of just using `pst` as a real-valued variable and setting upper/lower constraints?

Comment: I must split the pst variable because pst+ (positive value) is for discharging my battery and pst- is for charging my battery (negative value). Therefore pst can't be the same for charging and discharging. I don't understand the problem of the error.